# My css code isnt working on Atom and I think its something to do with the link tag?

Tags: css, atom-editor

I was trying to upgrade a website that I made on Atom with css but my code isnt working. When I was trying to use the style tag, my code seemed to work as expected but as soon as I tried to use a link tag instead it went back to how it was before. I really want to fix the issue. Here is the code on my main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> 

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>☆My Test Site☆</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>
```

Here is the code for a different file called styles.css:

```
body {
  background-color: #FFE6E6;
}

hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 5px;
  width: 5%;
}
```

Btw I have been double checking for over a day now so i dont think there is a problem with the file name.

Comment: Try `href="./css/styles.css"`

Comment: I tried doing what you said but it doesnt work: 
```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>☆My Test Site☆</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">

</head>
```

Comment: add this inside link tag:  type="text/css" and then try

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It turns out that my css folder wasnt on the same level as my other folder which had my main file in it!